# no body in php curl

Tags: php, curl

in this code snippet i want to curl $jsonArray to the url and get response body that must be a code but my problem is the only thing that it gives me it is a 1(true)

```
$array = [
    "type"=>"send",
    "phone"=>"989107786584"
];
$jsonArray = json_encode($array);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://79.175.166.98/chargebazi/otp.php');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,$jsonArray);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$responseCode = json_decode($result);
echo $responseCode;
```

Comment: How sure you are JSON is result?

Comment: `if(curl_exec($curl) === false){ $result = curl_error($curl);}` see what that tells you

Answer (score 5):

Add option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

and after `$result = curl_exec($curl);` add this block:

```
if ($result === false) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(curl_error($curl));
}
```

so you will be able to see errors.